# Getting current date details from the mysql table which were not present earlier

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table where every day production data gets loaded. I need the one column values(referral) which are not present for earlier dates i.e currentdate -1

I have tried various queries:

1)

```
select distinct referral from time_in_report where crt_date=curdate() and referral not in(select distinct referral from time_in_report where crt_date<curdate())
```

This above query is correct but, since the table has huge data, it take long time to respond and goes out of memory. So i cant use above query

2)

```
select distinct referral from time_in_report a where a.crt_date=curdate() and not exist(select 1 from time_in_report b where a.id=b.id and b.crt_date<curdate())
```

In above query, ID column is the Primary key in the table. Since one referral can have different ID, the above query result is not correct. I am getting some Referral which are exist for previous dates other than current date.

3. select distinct referral from time_in_report a where a.crt_date=curdate()
   minus
   select distinct referral from time_in_report a where a.crt_date

Minus is not working in my mysql version.

Please suggest your ideas as how to get the distinct referral for current date which are not present other dates except current date.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can check the field  with not equal to current date rather than minus the current date.

```
select distinct referral from time_in_report where crt_date=curdate() and referral not in(select distinct referral from time_in_report where crt_date!=curdate());
```

Try this out.

Answer (score 0):

The reasons for the inefficiency that mysql is showing because there could be missing indexes in the tables that you haven't provided during their design and MySQL optimizer not producing efficient plan because of the derived tables.

```
select distinct a.referral from time_in_report a left join time_in_report b
on
a.referal_basename=b.referal_basename where a.crt_date=curdate() and b.crt_date<curdate()
```

.

The above query may or may not work but you just try it. Its a alternative to minus query in mysql since minus operator is not present in mysql.. that is weird and its true.

If you have huge data then you should have indexes so that your data can be retrived by using not in query